# PCIe GPU help CPU-GPU

Tags: hdmi, gpu, integrated-graphics, acceleration

My new monitor only has DP and HDMI inputs. both my nvidia gpus have only 2 DVI outputs. My motherboard has a HDMI tough. Is it possible to set the system up in a way that I use the HDMI output of my motherboard, but the two nvidia GPUs act as accelerators or something like that?

Comment: Which nvidia GPUs do you have?

Comment: 2x nvidia GTX260

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the VooDoo accelerator cards that where popular 15 years ago, aren't you ?

No. That won't work.

The HDMI on the motherboard is strictly intended to be used for the build-in graphics provided by the CPU.
You can't use the GPUs on the Nvidia cards as "add on" accelerators. They deliver their own output on their own DVI ports.

DVI to DP and DVI to HDMI converters are cheap. Get some. That solves your problem.

Comment: amusingly, many ivy and sandy bridge era intel processors supported just that

Comment: dvi do dp, will that slow down graphics or decrease quality somehow? i need the ocmputer for photo editing.. Do you know a good dvi to dp converter? thank you!

Comment: @sharkyenergy DP is MORE capable than DVI. HDMI has (for this purpose) the same specs as DVI. When you use a DVI-> DP (or HDMI) converter the DVI signal is put though 1 on 1 without changes, so you will not loose anything in the conversion.

Comment: thanks, but all the products i was able to find so far are able to convert FROM DP (gpu) TO HDMI/DVI (monitor). i was not able to find a cable working the other way around..

Comment: Don't look for a cable, look for a converterplug. DVI male to HDMI or DP female